# How can I make two input boxes react at the same enter keystroke?

Tags: javascript, html, user-interface, user-input

I have the following code:

```
<div>
    <label style="font-size: 14px">Start Time: </label> <input #StartTime id="Stime" type="time" value="09:00" (keyup.enter)="function1(name2.value)"/><br>
    <label style="font-size: 14px">End Time: </label><input #EndTime id="Etime" type="time" style="margin:10px" value="getCurrentTime()" (keyup.enter)="function1(name1.value)"/>
</div>
```

I want to let the user insert the two values and then on enter I want both values to be recorded. the way it is now I have to input the time and press enter and then input the second value and then press enter again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bind a keyup listener to the document and then check if it is the enter key, if yes, get the values and do what you need with then.

Here in the example I'm just logging it.
And also, you can insert some validations before show/use the values, like check if both times aren't empty.

Please, see if is this what you need and tell me if need some changes.

```js
document.onkeyup = function(ev){
  if (ev.keyCode == 13){
    //YOU CAN INSERT VALIDATIONS HERE
    var startTime = document.getElementById('Stime').value;
    var endTime = document.getElementById('Etime').value;
    console.log("Start: " + startTime + " | End: " + endTime);
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
    <label style="font-size: 14px">Start Time: </label> <input id="Stime" type="time" value="09:00" (keyup.enter)="function1(name2.value)"/><br>
    <label style="font-size: 14px">End Time: </label><input id="Etime" type="time" style="margin:10px" value="getCurrentTime()" (keyup.enter)="function1(name1.value)"/>
</div>
```

Comment: you script was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you loads!

Answer (score 0):

```
function onClickMe()
{
    var newValue = $("#box").val();
    var startvalue = $("#Stime").val();
    if(startvalue != null and startvalue != "")
    {
        $("#Stime").val(newValue);
    }
    else
    {
        $("#Etime").val(newValue);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey. thanks for your answer! I may have worded my question wrong. It is just the two labels `Start Time` and `End Time`. they both have the enter `(keyup.enter)`

Comment: Please could you explain your answer?

Comment: Please explain the code. This is low quality answer at the moment

Comment: When user press enter in box textbox then the first time it will assign a value of box textbox to Stime textbox and for the second time it will assign a value from box textbox to Etime textbox

Comment: For example the user wants to select the limits of a line chart and he inputs 9:00 and 13:00 in the boxes provided, presses enter and then both values are recorded in the local namespace which in this case is an angular component (not angularJS)

Answer (score 0):

If you also want to update the times, then you have to listen to the keyup event also.

```js
document.onkeyup = function(ev){
  // for pressing enter or keyup event
  if (ev.keyCode == 13 || ev.keyCode == 38){ 
    var startTime = document.getElementById('Stime').value;
    var endTime = document.getElementById('Etime').value;
    console.log("Start: " + startTime + " \nEnd: " + endTime);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <label style="font-size: 14px">Start Time: </label> <input #StartTime id="Stime" type="time" value="09:00" (keyup.enter)="function1(name2.value)"/><br>
    <label style="font-size: 14px">End Time: </label><input #EndTime id="Etime" type="time" style="margin:10px" value="getCurrentTime()" (keyup.enter)="function1(name1.value)"/>
</div>
```